# bash: cd: E:\Immabeme Solutions: No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, git-bash

Whenever I opened my terminal in VS Code, it shows a message like this - "bash: cd: E:\Immabeme Solutions: No such file or directory". Then if I run any npm or yarn command it shows the "bash: npm: command not found" message. However, my node, npm and yarn are already installed on my computer. I uninstall and then reinstall the git but didn't work. Now, how can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: What does `node -v` return? Also since you're running inside bash, don't use windows style paths. Try `cd /e/Immabeme\ Solutions`

Comment: node -v return bash: npm : command not found. Also, node -v is working fine in the command prompt. but the first four lines are not written by me. It's automatically displayed whenever I opened gitbash terminal.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git. It's a configuration error you have in your bash startup scripts (`.bashrc` or `.profile`, probably). You'll need to locate and fix the error so that your startup scripts can proceed past the failing `cd` command and finish the rest of the bash setup, so that bash can find installed programs.

Answer (score 1):

Check first the content of your `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc` or `%USERPROFILE%\.profile`, since `%USERPROFILE%` is the default path considered by a bash session as its `$HOME`.

If there are any `cd` command in those, that would explain the initial error message.

Do an echo `$PATH` to check your PATH.
A bash session should inherit the %PATH% from your Windows user/system environment variable, so make sure `npm` works from a CMD first, then relaunch VSCode and open a terminal again.

Comment: Where can I change the path or content? I changed some default settings in the network setting. I don't know is this happening for this or not.

Comment: @RiyadHossain The idea is to make sure npm works in a CMD, [modifying the PATH in your Windows user environment variable](https://superuser.com/a/1002151/141). Then launch VSCode.

Comment: actually, the npm is running on CMD. I checked it. Even though I uninstall and reinstall the node but didn't work. To inform you, before I encountered this error, I add some content to Path in system variables in order to solve another problem.

Comment: @RiyadHossain OK. Then, when you open bash VSCode terminal session and type `echo $PATH`, do you find back the same Windows PATH as the one you have in your CMD?

Comment: if I type `echo $PATH` in the vs code terminal it shows `/c/Users/Riyad/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Riyad/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/windows/:/c/Program File:/c/Winnt:/c/Winnt/System32":/c/Windows/System32:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/cmd:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Users/Riyad/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/Riyad/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/Riyad/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl` . How can I find my CMD windows path?

Comment: @RiyadHossain By visually comparing it with `echo %PATH%` in a `CMD`. Since I see `/c/Users/Riyad/AppData/Roaming/npm`, the executable `npm.exe` should work.

Comment: At the beginning of this error, it showed some file paths like this `/c/Users/Riyad/AppData/Roaming/npm`. However, I don't find any file path like this. Now, the npm command is working automatically. But whenever I open the VS code terminal it shows `bash: cd: E:\Immabeme Solutions: No such file or directory
bash: E:Immabeme: command not found
bash: cd: C:\Immabeme Solution: No such file or directory
bash: cd: E:\Immabeme Solutions: No such file or directory`. I don't why this is showing. I created a file named 'Immabeme Solution' for cloning a project. Then I deleted it finding an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246127/discussion-between-vonc-and-riyad-hossain).